# API oriented web app for both public and private consumptions in Ruby

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, mvc, ruby, ruby-on-rails

In traditional Rail app, we need to deal with `controller/model/action` and has a `view` that generate HTML output. Now

1. There are many JS framework like *backbone/react* that allow us to code client side that consume API very easily.
2. And our webapp might also provide APIs for public to use.

I am thinking, instead of coding many *action/view* that generate the HTML output, why not even just treat us as a API consumer and build a completely API oriented app for both ourself and public.

Are there any caveat using this approach? or any existing tool/library/tutorial  worth to have a look?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few caveats.

1. Data security.  You will tend to expose far more data with an API than with a standard html page.
2. Performance.  SPA like applications tend to hit your server with many small requests as opposed to singular large requests.  This isn't a problem if you build your back end right.
3. Will you always be getting your API from JavaScript front ends on your domain?  You may have to think about CORS to allow cross domain JavaScript.
4. Does SEO matter?  If your Google search ranking matters you will have to research the best practices to ensure Google can properly understand your JavaScript site.
5. User security.  If you require authentication, youre likely going to need to implement a more complicated authentication mechanism like oauth.  In a normal html site CSRF tokens can be used to prevent cross site request forgery attacks.  If a session cookie or basic auth is used on your api your api will be potentially vulnerable CSRF attacks.